RubyOnRails + Mac M1 + While running rails server, got error missing psych for YAML output
I'm using a Mac M1 and running Ruby ruby 2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [-darwin23] and Rails 5.2 and I keep getting this error, which is making it impossible for me to do any kind of development in Rails.
While running rails s, got the below error on the console:

/Users/james/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/yaml.rb:5: warning:
It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output). To
eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your
ruby.

I tried to install libyaml and relink as well. Still not working.
Reinstall of ruby via rvm is done.

Upgrade your ruby and rails or use a docker image with needed dependencies.

Sorry, its a legacy project - so I can continue with this version.

Then your fastest path to working again is creating a docker image to use

This may help youb https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-ruby/issues/328

I'd suggest Docker as well, you can get known-good builds for Ruby versions going way back. It's very difficult for the Ruby maintainers to keep older versions working on newer operating systems, so post end-of-life they usually stop, which in the case of 2.5.x was in 2021. In any case, you may have some success here using the Psych gem: gem install psych.

What worked for me on an M2 Mac while running Ruby 2.5.3

Install or Reinstall libyaml:
brew install libyaml or brew reinstall libyaml

Install the Psych Gem:
gem install psych -- --with-libyaml-dir=$(brew --prefix libyaml)

Configure Ruby Installation with libyaml:
set this in ~/.zshrc ~/.bash_profile # Or the relevant shell configuration file if not using bash or zsh
export RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-libyaml-dir=$(brew --prefix libyaml)"

Reinstall Ruby using RVM:
rvm reinstall 2.5.3

Test Your Setup:
After reinstalling, close and reopen your terminal, or reload your configuration:


